# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'market' (most likely due to a circular import)-Flask

Tags: flask

```
#market package
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from market import routes
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config\['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'\] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
----------
from market import db #(models)
----------
from market import app #(routes)
from flask import render_template
from market.models import Item
----------#run
from market import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Structuring the code into packages then importing modules but  then getting the above error

Comment: I have a package called market with the models file, routes ,db  and the initialization file

Comment: first five lines are from  __init__.py  the second line is from models,The next three lines are from routes.py and the last three lines are from the run file.

Comment: Where could I be going wrong.....kindly assist

Comment: Ok, yes. A common solution to this problem is moving `from market import routes` in your market package to after the declaration of `app`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63652305/15368978) post for a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you Patrick that worked for me. I had to turn off auto formatting.